# JAX-RS and unknown query parameters

Tags: rest, jax-rs, query-string

I have a Java client that calls a RESTEasy (JAX-RS) Java server. It is possible that some of my users may have a newer version of the client than the server.

That client may call a resource on the server that contains query parameters that the server does not know about. Is it possible to detect this on the server side and return an error?

I understand that if the client calls a URL that has not been implemented yet on the server, the client will get a 404 error, but what happens if the client passes in a query parameter that is not implemented (e.g.: `?sort_by=last_name`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect this on the server side and return an error?

Yes, you can do it. I think the easiest way is to use `@Context UriInfo`. You can obtain all query parameters by calling `getQueryParameters()` method. So you know if there are any unknown parameters and you can return error.

> but what happens if the client passes in a query parameter that is not implemented

If you implement no special support of handling "unknown" parameters, the resource will be called and the parameter will be silently ignored.

Personally I think that it's better to ignore the unknown parameters. If you just ignore them, it may help to make the API backward compatible.

Comment: If the unknown query parameter represents a "hint", like sort order, then I agree that there is no harm in ignoring it, but if the query parameter is something like "/users?last_name=j*", meaning that the caller only wants users whose last name starts with "j", and the server returns all users, than might be a problem.

Comment: Before you answered the question, I had already come up with that, but was hoping for something better :-). I'm going to try to do something with annotations, so that the parameter checking method can scan through the resource method's parameter and automatically determine the allowed set of query parameters. I'm also looking into Aspects to allow a cross-cutting method to automatically check this (and other things, like security).

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out the JAX-RS filters (org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.RequestHandler) to intercept, validate, manipulate request, e.g. for security or validatng query parameters.

If you declared all your parameters using annotations you can parse the web.xml file for the resource class names (see possible regex below) and use the full qualified class names to access the declared annotations for methods (like javax.ws.rs.GET) and method parameters (like javax.ws.rs.QueryParam) to scan all available web service resources - this way you don't have to manually add all resource classes to your filter. 
Store this information in static variables so you just have to parse this stuff the first time you hit your filter.

In your filter you can access the org.apache.cxf.message.Message for the incoming request. The query string is easy to access - if you also want to validate form parameters and multipart names, you have to reas the message content and write it back to the message (this gets a bit nasty since you have to deal with multipart boundaries etc).

To 'index' the resources I just take the HTTP method and append the path (which is then used as key to access the declared parameters.

You can use the ServletContext to read the web.xml file. For extracting the resource classes this regex might be helpful

```
String webxml = readInputStreamAsString(context.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/web.xml"));
Pattern serviceClassesPattern = Pattern.compile("<param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>.*?<param-value>(.*?)</param-value>", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```