# REST SERVICES parameter request

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, restful-url

I am struggling with Restful webservices understanding. I am looking if any one can help on the below issue

I have an interface declared like below

```
@GET
@Path("xxxx")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}
public Response echo();
```

**The above interface has a method with no arguments or parameters**

If i hit **URL** like. `https://wwww.abc.com/echo` it works fine. Also, `https://wwww.abc.com/echo/k`
issues 404 method not found and it is true as i have not decalred **PathParam**.

Issue:

```
https://wwww.abc.com/echo?hello=1
```

says status 200 ok and returns data. This will be a hack for the service.
**Can anyone help me out here how to resolve this issue.**

Comment: What do you expect `https://wwww.abc.com/echo?hello=1` to return? Seems like it's working correctly.

Comment: @condit: My question is, i have no parameter declared in the method. How could the service returning data with parameter issued. Bug found while testing.

Comment: Unknown query parameters will be ignored. Perhaps have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635875/jax-rs-and-unknown-query-parameters